# How to rewrite URLs for readability

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have uploaded a couple of PHP testsites on my web host, but all the URLs end with a `.php`.

1. How can I convert  `/image.php?id=1` to `yoursite.com/image/1`?
2. How can I get the `$id` from `yoursite.com/image/1` if a visitor manually enters the URL?

Comment: You should have a look at URL rewriting using htaccess

Comment: Google "pretty URLs". This is one of the most asked questions ever.

Comment: This is a relevant question, phrased differently than others ... It is about programming web applications. Also, is this for apache or IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` file make sure you have

`RewriteEngine on` and do the following:

`RewriteRule ^image/([0-9]+)$ image.php?id=$1 [L]`

For instance:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^image/([0-9]+)$ image.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This is assuming you're running a webserver that can handle `.htaccess` - you may also need to enable `mod_rewrite`

Enabling this is dependent on the webserver you're running, if it's apache2 you could do

`a2enmod rewrite`

and `service apache2 restart`

in your terminal.

If you're unsure if it is enabled or not; you can do

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and look for mod_rewrite

Comment: Maybe you should also include the IIS equivalent. I'm pretty sure this is for apache, but the tags don't specify which webserver.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have any first hand experience with IIS :-( - sort of hoping someone with experience will add an IIS equivalent